# examples of ring, a maximum ideal and prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> 1. Give some examples of ring and a maximal ideal such that the maximal ideal is not a prime ideal of the ring.
> 2. Give some examples of ring and a prime ideal such that the prime ideal is not a maximal ideal of the ring.

**Maximal Ideal:**  Let R be a ring. A two-sided ideal I of R is called maximal if $I \neq R$ and no proper ideal of R properly contains I.

**Prime Ideals** Let R bea commutative ring. An ideal I of R is called prime if $I \neq R$ and whenever $ab\in I$ for elements a and b of R, either $a\in  I$ or $b\in I$.

I know the definitions but cannot form the examples atleast two for each case. Please give me examples in elaborate form as far as possible.

Comment: It would be good to make explicit that you use a definition of rings that doesn't require a multiplicative identity. Such structures are commonly called [rngs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for 1: $R=2\mathbb{Z}$, $I=4\mathbb{Z}$.

Hint for 2: $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=\{0\}$.

Comment: would you please elaborate.

Comment: @user1942348 Now it should be enough